# Python Server-Client Lottery Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am have an issue regarding a python assignment I was doing and would like to ask the community for some guidance. I am to use the **socket module** and **argparse** modules only for this assignment. I have created a socketserver.py file and a socketclient.py file. The connection between the server and client is fine. Now the purpose of the assignment is that the client is to send the Lottery game type, # of tickets, and # of lines per tickets using **argparse**. E.g. syntax for socketclient.py would be python3  -t Lotto_Max -n 2 -l 2. The output for the ticket game, ticket type and number of lines per ticket show up correctly on the server. However, they sometimes don't show correctly on the client, and am really stuck at the moment. Here is my following code....

### Server Code

````
```socketserver.py code```

import socket
from random import sample

def main():
    host = input("Please specify an IP address for this server's socket\t")
    port = int(input('Please speciy a port number above 1024 for this socket.\t'))

    kulmiye = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        kulmiye.bind((host, port))
    except socket.error as egeh:
        print('Socket bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(egeh[0]) + ' Message ' + egeh[1])

    print('Socket bind accomplished...\n')

    print("Listening for an incoming connection...")

    kulmiye.listen()
    conn, addr = kulmiye.accept()

    print('Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))

    while True:
        server_data = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        game_data = server_data.split(",")
        if not server_data:
            break
        if game_data[0] == "Lotto_Max":
            nval = int(game_data[1])
            lval = int(game_data[2])
            for nval in range(nval):
                for i in range(lval):
                    numbers = sample(range(1, 50), 7)
                    numbers.sort()
                    sortedd = str(numbers)
                    print(sortedd)
                print("--------------------")
                conn.sendall(sortedd.encode("utf-8"))
                #conn.sendall(bytes(str(numbers),'utf-8'))
                liners = "-----------------------"
                conn.sendall(liners.encode("utf-8"))
            print("From Client: " + str(game_data))
            conn.sendall(b'goodbye')
    #        server_data = input('#\t')
            break
        else:
            conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
````

### Client Code

````
```socketclient.py code```
import socket
import argparse

def client():
    host = input("Please specify the server's IP you want to connect to\t")
    port = int(input("Please specify the server's port you want to connect to\t"))

    kulmiye = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    kulmiye.connect((host, port))

#    client_data = input("#\t")
#    while True:
#        client_data = input()
#        if client_data == 'quit':
#            kulmiye.close()
#            sys.exit()
#        if len(str.encode(client_data)) > 0:
#            kulmiye.sendall(str.encode(client_data))
#            server_response = str(kulmiye.recv(1024), "utf-8")

#            print(server_response, end = " ")

    kulmiye.sendall(bytes(tvar.encode("utf-8")))
    kulmiye.sendall(bytes(','.encode("utf-8")))
    kulmiye.sendall(bytes(str(nval).encode("utf-8")))
    kulmiye.sendall(bytes(','.encode("utf-8")))
    kulmiye.sendall(bytes(str(lval).encode("utf-8")))

    server_data = kulmiye.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")


    while server_data != 'goodbye':
        server_data = kulmiye.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        print('Server: \n' + server_data)
        #        client_data = input("#\t")
        if not server_data:
            break
    kulmiye.close()

# this code block serves to give the user the ability to play lotto max
# with the amount of tickets and lines per ticket they would like

# Using the argparse module to allow the user to input command-line interfaces
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Welcome to OLG Gaming.')
parser.add_argument(
    '-t',
    type=str,
    help="Pick the lottery you want to play",
    required=True)
parser.add_argument(
    '-n',
    type=int,
    help="Pick the amount of lottery tickets you want to play",
    required=True)
parser.add_argument(
    '-l',
    type=int,
    help="Pick the amount of lines you would like to play",
    required=True)
# parser.add_argument('-o', type = str, help = "This is optional", required = False)

# parse_args will convert the argument strings into objects and will get
# stored in the cmdargs variable
cmdargs = parser.parse_args()

tvar = cmdargs.t  # the t string argument that gets parsed into an object will get stored into a variable called tvar
# the n integer argument that gets parsed into an object will get stored

# into a variable called nval
nval = int(cmdargs.n)

# the l integer argument that gets parsed into an object will get stored
# into a variable called lval
lval = int(cmdargs.l)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client()
```code```
````

### Server

python3 socketserver.py

- specify localhost as IP
- specify a port e.g. 4444

### Client

python3 socketclient.py -t Lotto_Max -n 1 -l 1

- specify an IP address to connect to the server (e.g. localhost or 127.0.0.1)
- specify a port to connect to e.g. 4444

When the connection establishes between client and server, the server receives the client input and prints it on its end the gametype (Lotto_Max), number of tickets and lines per ticket

Server will output the resultse.g.

[image: server side lottery]

However, the client won't receive it indefinitely. Usually it'll get it about 25% of the time, and I am not sure why

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum required to demonstrate the issue. It would also helpful to include the input, as well as the desired and observed output.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is here in the server:

```
server_data = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
```

`conn.recv(1024)` can receive any number of bytes from 0 (closed connection) to 1024.  The line above assumes the whole message is received every time, but when it fails it only gets part of the message.  Below I've modified your code so the server can process multiple client connections one at a time, and the client will connect/disconnect over and over again to hasten the failure:

Server:

```
import socket
from random import sample

def main():
    host = ''
    port = 4444
    kulmiye = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    kulmiye.bind((host, port))
    print('Socket bind accomplished...\n')
    print("Listening for an incoming connection...")
    kulmiye.listen()

    while True:
        conn, addr = kulmiye.accept()
        print('Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
        with conn:
            server_data = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
            print(f'server_data={server_data}')
            game_data = server_data.split(",")
            print("From Client: " + str(game_data))
            if server_data:
                if game_data[0] == "Lotto_Max":
                    nval = int(game_data[1])
                    lval = int(game_data[2])
                    for nval in range(nval):
                        for i in range(lval):
                            numbers = sample(range(1, 50), 7)
                            numbers.sort()
                            sortedd = str(numbers)
                            print(sortedd)
                        print("--------------------")
                        conn.sendall(sortedd.encode("utf-8"))
                        liners = "-----------------------"
                        conn.sendall(liners.encode("utf-8"))
                    conn.sendall(b'goodbye')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Client:

```
import socket
import argparse

def client():
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 4444

    kulmiye = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    kulmiye.connect((host, port))

    kulmiye.sendall(bytes(tvar.encode("utf-8")))
    kulmiye.sendall(bytes(','.encode("utf-8")))
    kulmiye.sendall(bytes(str(nval).encode("utf-8")))
    kulmiye.sendall(bytes(','.encode("utf-8")))
    kulmiye.sendall(bytes(str(lval).encode("utf-8")))

    server_data = kulmiye.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")

    while server_data != 'goodbye':
        server_data = kulmiye.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        print('Server: \n' + server_data)
        #        client_data = input("#\t")
        if not server_data:
            break
    kulmiye.close()

tvar = 'Lotto_Max'
nval = 1
lval = 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        client()
```

Here's the result after 100s of successful connections.  Note `server_data` between the successful and unsuccessful connection:

```
Connected with 127.0.0.1:12175
server_data=Lotto_Max,1,1
From Client: ['Lotto_Max', '1', '1']
[4, 7, 9, 12, 24, 31, 48]
--------------------
Connected with 127.0.0.1:12176
server_data=Lotto_Max,1,
From Client: ['Lotto_Max', '1', '']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\server.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\server.py", line 24, in main
    lval = int(game_data[2])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

`conn.recv(1024)` didn't receive the complete message (didn't get the final `1`).  TCP is a byte streaming protocol with no concept of message boundaries.  You're code is responsible to call `recv()` and buffer the data until you have a complete message.  You could send fixed-sized messages and call recv until you have that many bytes, terminate a message with a sentinel byte such as a newline(`\n`) and read until the sentinel is received, or send the size of the message first followed by the message bytes.

I won't solve it for you since it is an assignment, but as a hint `socket.makefile` can wrap the socket in a file-like object where you can call `.read(n)` to read exactly `n` bytes from a socket, or `.readline()` to read a `\n`-terminated line.

Here's a link to an answer of mine that demonstrates this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55840026/235698

Another example of the streaming nature of TCP is on the client side.  Sometimes, it prints:

```
-----------------------
Server:
goodbye
Server:
-----------------------goodbye
Server:

Server:
-----------------------
Server:
goodbye
```

The separate lines in the server:

```
conn.sendall(liners.encode("utf-8"))
conn.sendall(b'goodbye')
```

Sometimes get received by the single `recv` in the client:

```
server_data = kulmiye.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
```

Again, this is due to the streaming nature of TCP and no message boundaries.  If you sent each line terminated by a newline, you could call `recv()` a number of times until a newline was detected, then process just that line.

Another answer that illustrates this technique is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55186805/235698.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mark Tolonen for your guidance. I still need to brush up how to handle TCP data stream. Nevertheless, I was able to achieve more desirable results using numerous 
`conn.sendall` within my nested for loop. Happy camper!